# Project Reactor (core) under the hood

Tags: project-reactor

Is there any how-to or online explanation how does the reactor-core internally works? By internally I mean reactor main thread and a place, where event loop starts (lower level than provided in docs). I wanted to go deep into implementation of those features, but I cannot find this spot.